# Columns in random order in attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

First, I'm well aware of multiple ways to rearrange the order of the columns in the attribute table. I've used the *refactor* tool plenty to change permanently the structure of the table and I know I can right click on the headers and select *organize columns* (my traduction might be a little off since I use the French version, but you get it).

Anyway, My problem is I have layers and tables with around 150 attributes, which I need to be in a specific order. I used *refactor* on vector layer with great success. But now, for some reason, when I load tables from csv files, the order of the attributes is all messed up. I know my tables are right because when I get into the properties, under *field*, the fields are in the right order, with their ID number associated. That order is the same as in the csv files.

Why would QGIS mess up the attribute order when I load a table? I don't have time to re-order 150+ fields every time I load a table.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you [make a bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues), I recommend you attach some sample data, otherwise it will be difficult to reproduce.

Comment: 150 attributes is kind of a lot (not a *huge* number, but more than I usually have in a CSV). Can you do some more testing with CSV's with fewer attributes, and see if there's a cutoff. That would make the issue much easier for the developers to reproduce and solve.

Comment: I'll give it a try and file the bug report. Thanks!

Comment: This might also be related to a chosen style, if there's one. It's easy to apply attribute table settings from a .qml file which mess up column order if there has been some other changes meanwhile (e.g. refactor).